# WPF: How to play video (mp4 format) from servrer in MediaElement?

Tags: c#, json, wpf, mediaelement

I want to play video directly from the server in MediaElement. (The source will be the server)
I have a URL of the server:
http://videotherapy.co/dev/vt/api/dispatcher.php

And post the following json:

```
{"videoId":"22-1","api":"get-training-video"}

(where 22-1 is the videoId)
```

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="MediaElementApp.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="467.91" Width="1300">
<Grid>
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="418" Margin="246,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1036" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Source="Images\Wildlife.wmv" />
<Button x:Name="play" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="538,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="84" Click="play_Click" >
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/smiley.jpg"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>

</Grid>
```

c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MediaElementApp
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

        private void play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            mediaElement.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

How to do this?
I would like for help.

Comment: A minimal requirement would be for you to at least have tried something and come here when you encounter a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MediaElement` accepts a URI as `Source`. Like this, it can stream the video from the web to the client application.

If this is somehow not possible in your case. You'll have to download the video to a `File`. Then pass the location of this file to the `Source` property of the `MediaElement`

Comment: I should contact to the link using Json, I just do not know how.

Comment: For that, I suggest you use the .Net HttpClient: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx .